# Level up Monster Summer Badge with Wormhole?

Tags: steam-monster-game

Part of the description for the Wormhole ability says:

> You must defeat a boss level after using Wormhole in order to level up your Monster Summer Badge.

However, I have never used a wormhole and I have only defeated around 500-1000 bosses, yet my Monster Summer Badge is level 1880. Is that part of the description really true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That quotation means "if you use a Wormhole, you must then defeat a boss level to level up your Monster Summer Badge". In general, you level up the badge by defeating boss levels, and it's saying that using a wormhole to skip a boss level doesn't count for that purpose.

Comment: Well, I think it does count, but you have to defeat *another* boss after using it in order gain the levels.

Comment: I read it as, if you are on level 299,900 and your team uses 1000 WH to skip to level 309,900, you won't get the 300,000+ badge until you defeat a new boss.